# The difference between the udev rules and the proc sysfs for configuring the I/O scheduler?

Tags: linux, io

Under which circumstances are the following config methods appropriate for use?

1. "indirectly" use the udevadm via `/etc/udev/rules.d/<iosched_file>`:
   e.g.

   ```
   ACTION=="add|change", KERNEL=="sd[a-z]", ATTR{queue/iosched/low_latency}="1", ATTR{queue/scheduler}="cfq"
   ```
2. "directly" use the echo via `/sys/block/sd?/queue/scheduler`,  e.g.

   ```
    echo cfq > /sys/block/sda/queue/scheduler
   ```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

1. Both dynamically and statically for udevadm 
   a). "dynamically" means that the configuration can immediately take effects online , but not permanently after the system reboots.
   b). "statically" means that the configuration can permanently take effects after the system reboots.
2. Only dynamically for echo

Comment: Could you possibly describe more verbosely what you mean?

Comment: Where am I wrong 。。。？

Comment: The question is what you mean by "dynamically" and "statically" in the answer. I'm not saying that you're wrong, but I can't relate the answer to anything in the question.

Comment: Does deduct another mark。。。？